# !setBlockIndexCandidates.empty()

Tags: bitcoin-core

!setBlockIndexCandidates.empty() Bitcoin Core 0.11 error

Hello,

I have a problem with the Bitcoin Core v. 0.11 software!!!

I installed the software today and after a long wait (downloading block source - 5 years) I closed the application and when I tried to start it again I received this error:

"Assertion failed!
File: main.cpp, Line 2287
Expression: !setBlockIndexCandidates.empty()"

If I click Ignore on the error window the program start but with "No block source available" so it can't continue the download. And when I close the program I receive a FATAL ERROR message: "see debug.log for details"

Can somebody tell me how do I fix this error or what do I do next?
And another thing... 
I was sent today some Bitcoins and I am asking if the sun can be recovered somehow?

Thanks!

[debug.log](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=AV1B0UnK)

Comment: Can you take the last 30 lines or so of %APPDATA%\Bitcoin\debug.log and edit them into your answer?

Comment: Did you try to delete the `blocks` and `chainstate` directory in the bitcoin datadir?

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem with *litecoin* 0.15.1 and it helped me to run it with `--reindex` option on the command line. I only had to do it once...